# nginx rewrite url and remove last part

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Sorry if this question was asked many times. I can't make nginx do proper rewrite. I need to remove last part of the url. For example, this is the url I have:

```
https:/mydomain.com/this/is/some/url/page/0
https:/mydomain.com/this/is/some/url/page/1
```

I need to rewrite these both to this:

```
https:/mydomain.com/this/is/some/url
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
location / {

    ...
    rewrite ^/(.*)/page/0|1$ $1 last;

    ...
}
```

But it does not work. It seems to me that it is correct? What is wrong with that? (I hate regex).

**EDIT:**

```
location / {
    # Remove trailing double slashes.
    if ($request_uri ~ "^[^?]*?//") {
        rewrite "^" $scheme://$host$uri permanent;
    }
    # Remove trailing slashes.
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent; 

    # Rewrite page/0 and page/1 from url.
    rewrite ^/(.*)/page/[01]$ /$1 last;

    proxy_pass                      http://backend_web;
    proxy_set_header                Host $host;
    proxy_set_header                X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

Comment: The `rewrite...last` will change the URI passed through the proxy to `backend_web`. If you want to change the URI visible in the browser address bar, you will need to use `rewrite...redirect` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `0|1` should be within parentheses or redefined as a character class.

The rewritten URI needs a leading `/` as all `nginx` URIs have a leading `/`.

So all of these should be equivalent:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/page/(0|1)$ /$1 last;
rewrite ^/(.*)/page/[01]$ /$1 last;
rewrite ^(/.*)/page/[01]$ $1 last;
```

There's a useful website for regular expressions [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html).

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. But it does not remove the last part `page/0` or `page/1`. I edited the question. I added more details from the config.